# What TeX-related information to include in colophon?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, copyright

In the colophon a book, I want to include some information acknowledging the use of TeX and related software.

It tentatively includes the following:

```
Composed by the author using the \LaTeX2e{} Document \\
Preparation System originally developed by Leslie Lamport\\
(based on the \TeX{} system created by Donald Knuth),\\
the \textsf{memoir} \LaTeX document class (created by\\
Peter Wilson and maintained by Lars Madsen),\\
and the \textsf{amsmath} macros.\\
Typeset in \textsf{newtxtext} text fonts (based upon \textsf{\TeX Gyre Termes} fonts)\\
and MathTime\textregistered{} Professional II math fonts.\\
MathTime is a trademark of Publish or Perish, Inc.
```

Which parts, if any, of this are appropriate or inappropriate, and which things are missing? More specifically, which parts are:

- totally unnecessary; or
- *not* required, regarding copyright or trademark; or
- required regarding copyright or trademark but not already included; or
- desirable but not already included; or
- misstated?

I am ***not*** asking for legal advice! Just comments and suggestions based upon what you may know about this software.

Comment: I think it's mostly unnecessary but if you do have it `\LaTeX2e` should be `\LaTeXe`  Also not that it matters but Leslie developed LaTeX up to LaTeX2.09, so you should probably just say `\LaTeX` if you want to say it was originally developed by Leslie)

Comment: I do prefer books, whether technical or not, to tell me the fonts used!

Comment: Do you think all the information about TeX, LaTeX, and memoir are unnecessary. (See separate comment about fonts.)

Comment: I would say, all `\\ ` linebreaks seem totally unnecessary because tere is almost always a better way to get a ragged text block ;)

Comment: well it's up to you, but where does it end, you mention the current maintainer of memoir by name, but not those of latex or amsmath, you mention you are using txmth fonts but don't mention the developers of txmath or TeX gyre.   I certainly don't suggest making it _longer_ by adding more names so...

Comment: I personally like to advertise the use of `\LaTeX` when it was used and therefore second this approach. Regarding the other information I agree with the others, it is kind of strange to include some names, but not others and also are these all packages you used?

Comment: I'd mention the specifically things that were most useful to me or which were distinctive within the work.  Fonts, for example, are central, and usually named in a colophon along with names of the designers (e.g., "Lucida Bright by Bigelow & Holmes"). In your case, the reference to `newtxtext` would lead me to credit Michael Sharpe (others obviously developed most of the glyphs). I do think `\LaTeX` should be credited, but so many hands have gone into it that you just might credit "everyone who made it possible"? I use `TeXShop` often, and I credit that to Richard Koch.

Comment: No need to mention the `memoir` folk. I like to see font and setting information: for example (the colophon in my "A Few Notes on Book Design" `texdoc memdesign`) "The body text is set 10/12pt on a 33pc measure with Palatino designed by Herman Zapf, ...". Also sometimes the page size and the paper if it is a special type.